# Calling a web service that requires credentials: Error: A security token is required

Tags: vb.net, web-services, security, soa

When I try to call a [Java] web service from .NET, I am getting what appears to be a security credentials issue.

```
CWWSS5509E: A security token whose type is [http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken] is required.
```

Is it even picking up the credentials that I am trying to pass? At this point, I just want to make contact with the web service and get access. In my example, ServiceReference1 is a generated Web proxy class.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim myLocateProfileBySourceSystemId As New ServiceReference1.locateProfileBySourceSystemId

    Dim myLocateProfileBySourceSystemIdRequestType As New ServiceReference1.LocateProfileBySourceSystemIdRequestType

    myLocateProfileBySourceSystemIdRequestType.includeEmailAddress = True

    myLocateProfileBySourceSystemId.locateProfileBySourceSystemId1 = myLocateProfileBySourceSystemIdRequestType

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateRemoteCertificate)

    Dim myNetworkCredential As New System.Net.NetworkCredential
    myNetworkCredential.UserName = "MyUsernameGoesHere"
    myNetworkCredential.Password = "MyPasswordGoesHere"

    Dim myWebProxy As New WebProxy()
    myWebProxy.Credentials = myNetworkCredential
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = myNetworkCredential

    Dim myIndividualProfileSoapClient As New ServiceReference1.IndividualProfileSoapClient
    Dim myLocateProfileBySourceSystemIdResponse As ServiceReference1.locateProfileBySourceSystemIdResponse = myIndividualProfileSoapClient.locateProfileBySourceSystemId(myLocateProfileBySourceSystemId)

End Sub

Private Shared Function ValidateRemoteCertificate(ByVal sender As Object,
                                              ByVal certificate As X509Certificate,
                                              ByVal chain As X509Chain,
                                              ByVal policyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean    
     ' allow any old dodgy certificate...
     Return True

End Function
```

What should my App.Config settings be?

```
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                    realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
```

Comment: You should be able to add the credentials as a property to the myIndividualProfileSoapClient object

Comment: That object has a ClientCrdedentials  property that is of type System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials. It has a parameterless constructor but the Username and password properties of this object are readonly. How do I create this object?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf

and this

[Trying to get WCF client to work with wss 1.0 username token security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747654/trying-to-get-wcf-client-to-work-with-wss-1-0-username-token-security)

and this.

[Correct way communicate WSSE Usernametoken for SOAP webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836685/correct-way-communicate-wsse-usernametoken-for-soap-webservice)

```
ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ""
CleintCredentials.UserName.Password = ""
```

Comment: ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and ClientCredentials.UserName.Password would be correct

Comment: What about the <transport> clientCredentialType in teh config file? Should it be None as indicate in my posting? Basic? etc?

Comment: @Velika Yes Basic wasn't that section generated for you when you added the reference?

Comment: Transport and message are 2 different thing.  If the server hosting the web service is set up to require basic authentication then you want basic, otherwise you don't.  If the web service requires a SOAP Username Token then you want messageClientCredentialType= UserName.  It is possible you'd need both transport and message credentials, but I don't think you do.  It is hard to know without knowing the web service.

Comment: @mikey Yeah and base upon his error message i am betting the service needs a SOAP Username token. But without knowing what service it is your trying to consume its hard to go from here.